# Sverchok: Adding FreeCAD Dependency on Mac

Tags: python, sverchok

**I'm adding the Extra Nodes in Sverchok, but can't get FreeCAD connected.**

It seems to want to connect to a FreeCAD library in a folder, but the only option I could find on the FreeCAD site was to download a compiled app.

I tried setting the path to the bin folder inside the app – /Applications/FreeCAD.app/Contents/Resources/bin/ – but it still reports "FreeCAD package is not available".

*Do I need to connect to a specific file in the bin? Here's a screenshot of the contents:*

[image]

I've gone through the [Dependencies documentation on the Sverchok Github pages](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/wiki/Dependencies), but they don't offer a Mac-specific solution, and the Linux solution errors out because it can't find and run "apt".

Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you using MACOS, than you don't have apt.
Use your mac installer to install libfreecad-python3-0.18 somehow.
or try files from linux:
https://yadi.sk/d/qG5-IPfmqleeYw?w=1
if it will work, please, reply here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but no luck with either. I also pulled the files and stored them locally, but the addon wouldn't make the connection.